# How to start the inner for loop one position ahead the outer loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to replicate the exercise in the image. I'm using 2 loops to print a message from a String List. However, X and Y both begin at the same position ("TV"-"TV"). How can I start the inner variable at X+1, to avoid printing the duplicated cases?

I appreciate your help!

[image: My code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and [mcve] - in particular, your code needs to be within the question, not as an image or a link, and you should show an example input with the expected output.

Comment: @diego-acevedo: Please copy your program and data as text, not as an image.  (You could also try the Spanish version of Stackoverflow, https://es.stackoverflow.com which is happy to answer this kind of questions, but also needs text instead of images for code)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combinations` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get each x,y from the combination without repetitions:

```
from itertools import combinations

cols = list('abcd')
for x, y in combinations(cols, 2):
    print(f"{x}, {y}")
```

Output:

```
a, b
a, c
a, d
b, c
b, d
c, d
```

Alternatively, without `itertools`, you could do:

```
for i in range(len(cols)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(cols)):
        print(f"{cols[i]}, {cols[j]}")
```

But such is discouraged and seen as less "pythonic". `itertools` is a core library, specially meant for this kind of loops.